How to sync ADLS container with sharepoint site so that if a file is deleted from sharepoint, it gets deleted from ADLS too
We have copied all the files from multiple drives in the sharepoint site using Azure Data Factory pipelines and we have followed the same folder structure (heirarcy of folders) while copying the files. Now we want to make sure if a file is deleted from the sharepoint then it should be deleted from ADLS container.
We have created pipeline for two phase one getting files from Sharepoint and storing it in json format with name sitename_documentLibrary. Then we crawl adls container and call the respective json file. Here we are missing the folder structure. If in one document library there are A and B folder both have 1.txt it will create a mess because important files may delete. So please suggest me alternate approach for this.

To sync file deletions from SharePoint to an ADLS container, you can use Azure Logic Apps with a SharePoint trigger to start a Data Factory pipeline that deletes the corresponding file from ADLS, maintaining folder structure via parameters. Alternatively, use Azure Event Grid to trigger an Azure Function that deletes the file from ADLS using the Azure Storage SDK, also maintaining folder structure through parameters.
